# $[\partial^\rho,x^\mu]=g^{\rho\mu}$ (quantum field theory)

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

This is from a book by Srednicki:

> [image]

I can't make sense of the third equality. I suppose that $x^\mu$ is the projection operator. How can it be that $[\partial^\rho,x^\mu]=g^{\rho\mu}$?
I know that $g^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\rho\cdot\partial^\mu$, but this does not lead me anywhere. I think that my confusion arises from not knowing exactly what $x^\mu$ is.

Comment: $x^\nu$ is the operator for pointwise multiplication by the $\nu$-th coordinate.
$\partial_\nu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$ is the operator for taking partial derivative against $x^\nu$.
By definition $\partial^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}$.

Comment: @achillehui Yes, but I just get
$$
    \partial^\rho x^\mu - x^\mu \partial^\rho = g^{\rho\alpha}\partial_\alpha x^\mu - x^\mu g^{\rho\beta}\partial_\beta
$$

Comment: @achillehui and this would yield the result that we want if the second term vanishes and the first term is $g^{\rho\mu}$. But I don't see how the second term should vanish, and since $x^\mu$ is not the projection operator I'm not sure that $\partial_\alpha x^\mu = \delta_\alpha^\mu$

Comment: Let $\phi(x)$ be any state, $[ \partial_a, x^b ] \phi(x) = \partial_a(x^b \phi(x)) - x^b \partial_a(\phi(x)) = \delta_a^b \phi(x) + x^b \partial_a(\phi(x)) - x^b \partial_a(\phi(x)) = \delta_a^b \phi(x)$. i.e. applying $[\partial_a, x^b]$ to any state is equivalent to pointwise multiplication by $\delta_a^b$.